# Tracking Gmail Promo Tab

Tags: gmail-promo-tab

everyone!

I'd like to know how can be possible to track all users that engaged with the new Gmail annotations (for example the deal and featured image).
Today there are a lot number of factors to display all resources. So, isn't possible apply a simple A/B test and check what test generated the best open rate. So, how can we measure the new feature efficiency/metrics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All marketing email in the promo tab can populate in the bundle. The annotation allows you to take advantage of the additional real estate with the enriched preview features and your annotated logo displaying in the Primary tab teaser. What you include in the enriched preview will have the highest impact on the lifts.

However, tracking is tricky because in email impressions are not tracked and this is what you are asking for. However, the goal is that as you annotate all email in the promo tab/at scale, the lifts become more apparent in your standard metrics.